# Moving the login panel to center of screen

Tags: html, css, django

While practicing Django, I want to mess around with CSS. In this case, I am creating a login page. The login form is currently appearing at the top-left corner of the page. How to I modify to make it right in the center? I am not good with CSS and could use some pointers.
Here are my django files. I try to manipulate the `panel-default` but it does not work.

`base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <span class="logo">My Page</span>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`login.html` (which extends the base.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <h1>Log-in</h1>
  <form method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log in"></p>
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.css`

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli);

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.panel-default{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#header {
    padding:10px 100px;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#12c064;
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:4px solid #1cdf78;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `.panel-default` this CSS- `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`

and if you didn't give the parent element of `.panel-default` CSS `position: relative;` yet, please do it first.

Answer (score 1):

Align the panel to the center this way:

```
.panel{
           margin: 0px auto;
  }
```

If it doesn't work, then wrap your login form with div tags and align the new div to the center using the the margin property above.